# How to send this.state from a component to relay root container

Tags: javascript, relay

I want to change my root query parameter based on the `this.state.eventid` which is a child component, but I have no clue how to get props to relay root container. I started based on relay-starter-kit.

I have React component that has a dropdown menu, and onSelect it setStates for eventId

```
   renderAttend() { 
    if (this.props.groups != null && this.state.success != true)   {

    var events = this.props.events.map(function(event){ 

        var boundSelect = () => {this.setState({eventid:event.nodes[0].id})}

        return <MenuItem style={{fontSize:20}}eventKey={event.nodes[0].id} onSelect={boundSelect.bind(this)}>{event.nodes[0].properties.summary} / {event.nodes[0].properties.start}</MenuItem>

                },this)


    var teams = this.props.groups.map(function(team){
        var boundSelect = () => {this.setState({teamid:team.nodes[0].id})}
        return <MenuItem style={{fontSize:20}}eventKey={team.nodes[0].id} onSelect={boundSelect.bind(this)}>{team.nodes[0].properties.name}</MenuItem>
                },this)


        return (
                <div>

        <ButtonGroup>
        <DropdownButton style={{padding:"15px",fontSize:20}}title="Events" id="bg-vertical-dropdown-2">
        {events}
</DropdownButton>
<DropdownButton style={{padding:"15px",fontSize:20,marginLeft:"5px"}} title="Groups" id="bg-vertical-dropdown-2">
  {teams}
</DropdownButton>

</ButtonGroup>
        </div>
            )

}
}
```

I want to use this state to somehow change my root query...
my approute...
import Relay from 'react-relay';

```
 export default class extends Relay.Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
 eventId: {required: false}
  };

 static queries = {
    Event : () => Relay.QL`query{eventState(eventId:$eventId)}`,
  };

  static routeName = 'AppHomeRoute';

 }
```

and my app.js

```
  import 'babel-polyfill';

 import App from './components/App';
 import AppHomeRoute from './routes/AppHomeRoute';
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import Relay from 'react-relay';



  ReactDOM.render(
   <Relay.RootContainer
    Component={App}
   route= {new AppHomeRoute}
   renderLoading={function() {
   return <div style=         {{display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",marginTop:"55px"}}>  <h1>Loading...</h1></div>;
   }}
   renderFailure={function(error, retry) {
    return (
     <div>
        <h1>Click Refresh</h1>
      </div>
   );
   }}


    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Now I want to this.state.eventid from the react component to update my root query, but I have no idea how to pass data from child component to react root.container. I do not want to use react-router for this :)
p.s. this.props.events were passed to me by an ajax call so they are not saved in relay/graphql data.

Comment: I couldn't relate what you're trying to do and the example you've given. Can you please elaborate or revise your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a case, the better thing to do is to wrap your root query into a story like

```js
{
  store {
    events(eventId:$eventId)
  }
}
```

So in the root query you only have

```js
export default class extends Route {
  static queries = {
    app:() => Relay.QL`query { store }`
  };

  static routeName = "AppRoute";
}
```

And in the page you create a fragemnt like

```js
let RelayApp = createContainer(SomeComponent, {
  initialVariables: {
    eventId: null
  },
  fragments: {
    app: () => Relay.QL `
      fragment on Store {
        id
        events(eventId: $eventId) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              name
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});

export
default RelayApp;
```

For the child component, you set the eventId and onChange event handler as props from parent component. And in the parent componet you implement the event handler and call this.props.setVariables({eventId: someVal}) like

```js
// Child Component

export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => this.props.selectItem(val)}>{val}</li>
        ...
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

// Parent Component

class Main extends Component {
  _selectItem = (val) => {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({eventId: val});
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Menu selectItem={() => this._selectItem}/>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}

let RelayApp = ...

export default Main
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy way to solve this. Either use react-router-relay or nest your query like this and use `this.props.relay.setVariables()`

```
viewer {
    eventState(eventid:$eventid) {
        data
    }            
}
```